# Solving a set of implicit equations involving Polylogarithms

Tags: systems-of-equations, mathematica, polylogarithm, implicit-function

I have the following simultaneous equations:

\begin{aligned}
&H(\lambda) = a\, \text{Li}_{3/2}\left(b\frac{H(\lambda)}{F(\lambda)}\right), \; \\&H(\lambda)  = c\, \text{Li}_{3/2}\left(d \, \lambda \,{F(\lambda)}\right)
\end{aligned}

where a,b,c,d are real positive numbers and $\text{Li}_{3/2}(z)$ is a Polylog function. I need to find $H({\lambda})$ and $F(\lambda)$ as functions of $\lambda$.

Any suggestions on how to proceed? Can we solve them atleast numerically if not analytically?

Comment: There are an infinite number of pairs $H,F$ that will satisfy this equation.

Comment: Do you say this because the polylog function is multivalued?

Comment: No. I say it because I can choose any real number $t$ and set $F(\lambda)=t$ and $H(\lambda)=c\operatorname{Li}_{3/2}(d\lambda t)$.

Comment: But $F(\lambda) = t$ will not be consistent with $H(\lambda) = a \text{Li}_{3/2}(b \frac{H(\lambda)}{t}) = c \text{Li}_{3/2}(d \lambda t)$ for all possible $t$. I'm sorry if I'm missing something trivial here.

Comment: My mistake, I was going off of the second equation - can you explain how they are connected?

Comment: I guess I was not very clear, I have edited the post now. I want $H(\lambda)$ and $F(\lambda)$ which respect both the equations simultaneously.